# how do i optimize this (this is a minecraft shader)

Tags: c, glsl

```
#version 120

#extension GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 : enable

varying vec4 texcoord;

uniform sampler2D gcolor;
uniform sampler2D gnormal;
uniform sampler2D gdepth;

const int RGBA16 = 1;
const int gcolorFormat = RGBA16;

void main(){
    vec3 finalComposite = texture2D(gcolor, texcoord.st).rgb;
    vec3 finalCompositeNormal = texture2D(gnormal, texcoord.st).rgb;
    vec3 finalCompositeDepth = texture2D(gdepth, texcoord.st).rgb;

    gl_FragData[0] = vec4(finalComposite, 1.0);
    gl_FragData[1] = vec4(finalCompositeNormal, 1.0);
    gl_FragData[2] = vec4(finalCompositeDepth, 1.0);
}
```

after i added
const int RGBA16 = 1;
const int gcolorFormat = RGBA16;
it destroyed my frame rate how can i optimize this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
const int RGBA16 = 1;
const int gcolorFormat = 1;
```

And if that still mysteriously destroys your framerate, just use #define instead.

```
#define RGBA16 1
#define gcolorFormat RGBA16
```